# Svelte-apollo modify query data

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have the following code

```
<script>
import { query } from "svelte-apollo";
import { ME } from "../graphql/queries/me";

const me = query(ME);
</script>

{#if $me.loading}
   loading
{:else}

  {$me = $me.data.user}

{/if}
```

This technique works but it actually displays the `$me` object on the screen.

How can I modify the `$me` object once it finishes?

I've tried doing something like the following:

```
$: me = (async () => {
    let result = await $me
    if(result.loading) return result;
    return result.data.user
  })()
```

But I get the error of:

> TypeError: store.subscribe is not a function